# c++ attaching to thread (taking focus)

Tags: c++, macos, qt, focus

So, (I rewrote this since a lot of people didn't understand me. I apologize.)

I'd like to bring the window of my qt application to the very front of ALL windows on screen.

I've heard you can do this by attaching to the thread of the foreground window and then "stealing focus" aka putting yourself where that foreground window was.

(I'm using OSX, so windows.h is no option for me.)

I hope you understand now.

Comment: But this is a platform-specific question, not a C++-specific question.  (Plus, it's not really about threads per se.  And I'm not sure what you think you mean by "Stock C++".)  It's about the window systems on each platform, and their APIs.  On OS X, it's really a Cocoa question, and you're more likely to do something like this in Cocoa with Objective-C or Swift than with C++.  On Windows, it's a Windows API question, which is more C than C++, or, in Windows 8, it could be a .NET question or even a JavaScript/RT question, as those are both also "first class" OS APIs.

Comment: If you want a solution that isn't cross platform then what platform do you want it to work on?

Comment: I have written it incorrectly. Read it again xP

Comment: Please let us know what you mean by attaching to a thread. The noun *focus* has a very specific meaning when it comes to GUIs - it simply means the window or control that receives keyboard input. I have no idea whatsoever what you want to do, as threads and window focus have little to do with each other. You may wish to describe a scenario instead of presuming a particular technical solution.

Comment: I rewrote the question. Hopefully it's understandable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bring a window to the front, [ensure the window is visible](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#show), then [activate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#activateWindow) the window.

As the docs state: -

> Sets the top-level widget containing this widget to be the active window.

And

> If you want to ensure that the window is stacked on top as well you should also call raise().

So, assuming you have a window called pWindow, you can do something like this: -

```
pWindow->raise();
pWindow->show();
pWindow->activateWindow();
```

Also note that OS X can have multiple desktops (Spaces). If you also want the window to track the user's Space when they switch between them, you can add this function to your window class: -

```
void MyWindow::DisplayOnAllSpaces()
{
    // ensure we stay on the active desktop
    WId windowObject = this->winId();
    objc_object* nsviewObject = reinterpret_cast<objc_object *>(windowObject);
    objc_object* nsWindowObject = objc_msgSend(nsviewObject, sel_registerName("window"));
    int NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces = 1 << 0;
    objc_msgSend(nsWindowObject, sel_registerName("setCollectionBehavior:"), NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces);
}
```

Comment: I'd vote up, however I don't have sufficient reputation.